# Inverting color with mix-blend-mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with `mix-blend-mode:difference`, I want to invert color, and on white background my text must be black but on `linear-gradient` must be white, here is my code and screenshot of current status:

```
  .background-block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, #574791 15%, #3F5C94 70%, #306B95 94%);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform-origin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```
.title-two-homepage {
    font-size: 94px !important;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: "sohne-var","Helvetica Neue","Arial",sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: #15173B;
    opacity: .9;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

[image]

thanks for any help!